# Arduino MKR GSM/NB + CAN + SD Card

Tags: arduino

I have some questions about a new Arduino project I'm starting:

1. Since Vodafone (Italy in my case) is shutting down 3G in 2021 (keeping 2G/4G up apprently), is ARDUINO MKR GSM 1400 still valid in next years?
2. Does Arduino MKR NB 1500 work with classic 4G sim too? On the website they claim it works with LTE's Cat M1/NB1 bands but I have a Thingsmobile all-in-one sim card I'd like to use. It's a virtual Telco popular for M2M.
3. Can ARDUINO MKR MEM SHIELD and ARDUINO MKR CAN SHIELD co-exist together even if they both use SPI?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is a bit too broad, it covers 2 very different topics (Cellular radios and SPI buses). Please try and keep questions to a single topic in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The [spec](https://content.arduino.cc/assets/Arduino_SARA-U2_DataSheet_%28UBX-13005287%29.pdf) sheet for the radio module says it is a HSPA and 2G module, HSPA is "3G". So yes this should continue to work assuming that the local 2G network runs on one of the supported frequency bands.
2. That is a question for your SIM provider, the only way to be sure is to ask them directly.
3. You can have multiple devices on a SPI bus, but they each need their own Chip Select pin to enable each module separately so they don't clash.